# Cannot connect to localhost on docker

Tags: java, docker, localhost, gitlab

I am using the integrated CI in Gitlab that uses docker.
My source code has been placed on the box and using maven, I build a simple web service with Spring which runs as an executable jar.

The issue is when I attempt to connect to the web service using
`curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

"curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused" is returned.

Now because the docker image is one I have created I can use `docker run -t -i <container name> /bin/bash` to logon to the container locally and test the actions. In that case I am able to get a response from the web server.

Does anyone know why using `curl` on the gitlab infrastructure does not work?

Please note I have also tried:

- curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8080/
- curl -I http://0.0.0.0:8080/
- curl -I http://localhost:8080/

Comment: What is your host operating system? Localhost will only work using Linux

Comment: I believe it is CoreOS, which is used.
This is my maven output in the log
`OS name: "linux", version: "4.5.0-coreos-r1", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

Comment: Did you expose port 8080 of the container during the run command with `-p 8080:8080`?

Comment: I did not perform a run command, it is launched by GitLab whenever a Git Push is performed

This is the output on the container,
    `$ cat /etc/*-release
    PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
    NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
    VERSION_ID="8"
    VERSION="8 (jessie)"
    ID=debian
    HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
    SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
    BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"`

Comment: You confuse `docker exec`, which connects in a running container, and `docker run` which creates a new container

Comment: @user2915097 I used `docker run` to verify the image I was creating. I have never used `docker exec`, does `docker exec` prevent the use of localhost?

Comment: docker exec connects in a running container, nothing more, see it as the SSH of docker, and it does not prevent the use of localhost. Can you post `docker port your_container`?

Comment: I do not start the docker, it is created and started by GitLab CI
See https://gitlab.com/help/ci%2Fquick_start/README

Comment: Use docker inspect and check what ports are exposed

Comment: @Shibashis Using docker inspect, on my image that is used in the CI, I cannot see anything that related to ports.

Comment: how do you start the gitlab ? is it docker container ? how does gitlab starts docker container ? localhost & port is related with this setup for networking .